# Google spreadsheet point or comma always comma as decimal divider

Tags: google-sheets

There is always trouble with google spreadsheet once it comes on data entry of numbers. When use the US keyboard every keystroke works fine, except the point, which need to be a comma.
You can change this by ctrl+shift or any other methode. However, it's a pain for everyone who need to switch between different keyboard country layouts.

What I want is a function what always makes a comma as decimal seperator, no matter what keyboard layout the user use.

```
T4 = cell with data entry
=CONCATENATE(left(T4;len(T4)-3);",";right(T4;2))
```

This formula works, until the data entry is something like 12.3

Anyone an idea how to make this work in all situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2;".";","))`

Comment: since januari 2019 this doesn't work anymore.   see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361004/did-google-change-the-function-value

Answer (score 0):

Try just formatting the input number(T4) 1,000.12 through the format menu.