# Did Google change the function VALUE()?

Tags: google-sheets

"one thousand dollar and one cent" is notated in USA as `1000.01` and in the rest of the world `1000,01`

To solve this problem I convert the entered amounts with the formula below

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";",")
```

This formula converts both `1000,01`  and `1000.01`  into   `1000,01`

But the very same formula which worked well over all the years, gives a now `100001` as result

Am I the only one with this problem?
Or did Google changed something?

example spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HfNEGVjzwf6Xil7vbv69F3ii6nryyDh8f6Z2ELqS5N8/edit?usp=sharing

UPDATE:
It seems that it depend on the user.
Some users get the right values while others get a 100 fold of those values in the same spreadsheet at the same moment.

See also:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/how-to-convert-all-numbers-regardless-of-decimal-separator-into-valid-number-of

Comment: It seems in Europe many spreadsheets don't work anymore. I see multiple comments in social media. Not only value() works different, but refer to a cell with a value notated with comma decimal seems not to considered as a number anymore

Comment: USA isn't the only one country that use a dot as decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

the sheet you provided as an example is Netherlands locale where **`1000,01`** is a valid number (you can test it with **`=ISNUMBER(A2)`**) that's why **`=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A3; "."; ",")`** works.

fyi. - having  **`=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2; "."; ",")`** for **`1000,01`** is double overkill because **`1000,01`** is already numeric value and also there is nothing to be substituted

if you use a spreadsheet with US syntax than a valid number is **`1000.01`**, therefore, substituting **`.`** with **`,`** will invalidate it - that's why you got **`#VALUE!`** (because logic says: to output value from invalid source - kinda same as **`=VALUE("red")`**)

localization settings can be changed here:
[image: 4]

Comment: @Richard related (in a way) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365024/same-spreadsheet-same-cell-but-different-results-with-different-user/54365220#54365220

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what is going on.

Comment: @Richard its exactly whats going on

Answer (score 1):

The formula on the question requires that the value on A1 be a text. On the linked spreadsheet the above formula fails because the value of the referred cell is a number that use dot as thousand separator and comma as decimal separator.

The following should work both with numbers and text as input:

`=IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A4;"0,00"); ","; ".")); VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A4;"0.00"; "."; ","))))`

---

From [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79081/88163) to [How to convert all numbers regardless of decimal separator into valid number of current locale?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/79051/88163)

> The following formula does the job (tested with U.S. and Russia as
>   locales, where separators are different):
>
> ```
> =IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, ",", ".")), VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, ".", ",")))
> ```
>
> Explanation:
>
> - [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) returns the first argument unless it throws an error, in which case it returns the second.
> - The first argument of `IFERROR` is the result of converting the text, with any commas replaced by dots, into a number.
> - The second argument of `IFERROR` is the result of converting the text, with any dots replaced by commas, into a number.
>
> I'm assuming that in every locale, one of two things is going to work.

Comment: Thank you @Rubén but this was exactly the solution I used, but overnight it didn't worked anymore.  Google changed the way how it handle value()  and in some rare cases it works different. (I found a few people who had exactly the same problem which suddenly occur on since Januar 25th.  I made a workaround for my spreadsheets (data validation)