# Same spreadsheet, same cell, but different results, with different user

Tags: google-sheets, decimal-point, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem with Google sheets since today.
The spreadsheet I use to get an amount from a different sheet (within the same spreadsheet).

But the same sheet gives different results depending on who is the user.

[image: https://snag.gy/BWVi1w.jpg]

In the example in this image it's `Cell J5` for `user A` it is `€ -50,00` but for `user B` it is `€ -5000,00`
It seems something to do with value()  (it's what I saw on twitter, as many people suffer from this problem since today)

Once their function value is used. (To convert text to a number) It goes wrong depending on the user.

But I can not find out a difference between settings in user A and user B

My question is:

Does anyone already know how to solve this issue (which seems to occur since today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **US syntax:**

  - **`=VALUE(1.1)`** = **`1.1`**
  - **`=VALUE(1,1)`** = **`#N/A`** or **`#VALUE!`**
- **EU syntax:**

  - **`=VALUE(1,1)`** = **`1,1`**
  - **`=VALUE(1.1)`** = **`#N/A`** or **`#VALUE!`**

**the difference between the two spreadsheets you are looking for is locale settings:**

[image]